# django ORM разный вывод одного QuerySet для шаблона и shell

Tags: django, django-orm

Прошу помощи:

QuerySet запрос один, но в оболочке shell выдает нужный результат, а в шаблоне нет

Имеется таблица в базе данных

```
date                 book   news
2021-11-29 11:35:00  15     15
2021-11-28 09:35:00  14     18
2021-11-28 10:35:00  11     20
2021-11-29 09:35:00  11     15
2021-11-29 10:35:00  16     11
2021-11-28 11:35:00  10     12
```

Поле date - CharField

Необходимо чтобы была группировка по дате без времени, т.е 2021-11-28 и максимальное число по столбцу book и news за это число
В итоге чтобы в шаблон отправлялся QuerySet:

```
[{'date': '2021-11-28', 'max_book': '14', 'max_news': '20'},
{'date': '2021-11-29', 'max_book': '16', 'max_news': '15'}]
```

Имею класс

```
class test(ListView):
    model = UseTest
    template_name = 'test/use_test.html'
    context_object_name = 'usetest'
    result = (UseTest.objects
             .annotate(newdate=Left('datemaxagent', 10), max_book=Max('book'), max_news=Max('news'))
             .values('newdate', 'max_book', 'max_news')
             .annotate(totals=(F('max_book') + F('max_news')))
             )
    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
      context = super(test, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
      context['title'] = 'Тестовая страница'
      return context
      
    def get_queryset(self):
      return self.result
```

В оболочке shell выводит QuerySet, который нужен:

```
>>> result = (UseTest.objects
...              .annotate(newdate=Left('datemaxagent', 10), max_book=Max('book'), max_news=Max('news'))
...              .values('newdate', 'max_book', 'max_news')
...              .annotate(totals=(F('max_book') + F('max_news')))
...              )
>>> print(result)
<QuerySet [{'newdate': '2021-11-28', 'max_book': 14, 'max_news': 20, 'totals': 34}, {'newdate': '2021-11-29', 'max_book': 16, 'max_news': 15, 'totals': 30}]>
>>>
```

Через shell в итоге видим

```
<QuerySet 
[{'newdate': '2021-11-28', 'max_book': 14, 'max_news': 20, 'totals': 34},
 {'newdate': '2021-11-29', 'max_book': 16, 'max_news': 15, 'totals': 30}]
>
```

А на сайте QuerySet {{ usetest }} имеет другой значение, он выводит все. (примечание: на всякий случай почему тут не result или object_list, а usetest -> context_object_name = 'usetest')

```
<QuerySet 
[{'newdate': '2021-11-28', 'max_book': 10, 'max_news': 12, 'totals': 22}, 
{'newdate': '2021-11-28', 'max_book': 11, 'max_news': 20, 'totals': 31}, 
{'newdate': '2021-11-28', 'max_book': 14, 'max_news': 18, 'totals': 32}, 
{'newdate': '2021-11-29', 'max_book': 11, 'max_news': 15, 'totals': 26}, 
{'newdate': '2021-11-29', 'max_book': 16, 'max_news': 11, 'totals': 27}, 
{'newdate': '2021-11-29', 'max_book': 15, 'max_news': 15, 'totals': 30}]
>
```

Запрос result один и тот же, но в оболочке shell и в шаблоне результаты разные.

Так же странно работает paginate_by не важно с каким значением, например paginate_by = 10, то почему то QuerySet в шаблоне обрезается до 2х записей,
причем берет первые записи из QuerySet, который содержит все записи (см выше), а кол-во 2 потому что при group by выводилось именно 2 строки.

```
<QuerySet 
[{'newdate': '2021-11-28', 'max_ccloud': 10, 'max_ccs3': 12, 'totals': 22}, 
{'newdate': '2021-11-28', 'max_ccloud': 11, 'max_ccs3': 20, 'totals': 31}]
>
```

Попробовал через функцию:

```
def TestUse(request):
    result = UseTest.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(result, 4)

    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)
    return render(request, 'test/use_test.html', {'page_obj': page_obj})
```

Меняю запрос в result

```
def TestUse(request):
    result = (UseTest.objects
             .annotate(newdate=Left('datemaxagent', 10), max_book=Max('book'), max_news=Max('news'))
             .values('newdate', 'max_book', 'max_news')
             .annotate(totals=(F('max_book') + F('max_news')))
             )
    paginator = Paginator(result, 4)

    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)
    return render(request, 'test/use_test.html', {'page_obj': page_obj})
```

Выводит две первые строки, т.е так же как и через класс и так же странно работает pagination. Просьба помочь разобраться как получить в шаблоне QuerySet, такой же как и в оболочке Shell. В Shell отображается верный.

Answer (score 0):

Насторожила некорректная работа pagination.
Суть в том, что не работала сортировка и он выдавал первые две записи QuerySet.
**Добавил order_by('newdate')** и получил нужный результат

```
result = (UseTest.objects
             .annotate(newdate=Left('datemaxagent', 10), max_book=Max('book'), max_news=Max('news'))
             .values('newdate', 'max_book', 'max_news')
             .annotate(totals=(F('max_book') + F('max_news')))
             .order_by('newdate')
             )
```